# Extract substring using windows findstr and regular expressions

Tags: string, windows, findstr

I've searched through the already asked questions and altough i found some interesting answers, i'm not able to apply those answers to my specific case
My apologies if you'll find me too stupid :(

Here's the situation :

I have an html file that contains several lines looking like that :

```
<h3 class ="title-3"><a href="/product/PD00334951.html">Title name nb 1</a></h3>
<h3 class ="title-3"><a href="/product/PD00397772.html">Title name nb 2</a></h3>
<h3 class ="title-3"><a href="/product/PD00324955.html">Title name nb 3</a></h3>
...
```

Using the windows command line tool findstr (and only that tool), i'm trying to check if it's possible to extract just the /product/PDxxxxxxxx.html substring

Any guess ?
Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally switched to PowerShell so that string manipulation would be easier
No need to answer any longer